# Правильно ли некачественную отвратительную рыбу без структуры, одной массой называть клёклой?

Tags: терминология

Я имею в виду готовую рыбу холодного или горячего копчения. Бывает такая однородная рыба, у которой не видно волокон, и её есть противно.

Answer (score 1):

1. Слово ***клеклый*** мне незнакомо,  скорее я слышала ***квёлый***, которое есть в словаре, и оно более частотное. КВЁЛЫЙ,  Разг. Слабый, хилый; вялый. Человек он хороший,  но квелый. Чаще употребляется по отношению к людям, но есть и такие примеры: травка под навесом квелая.
2. ***Клеклый***  в словаре Ефремовой помечено как местн. 1. Ссохшийся, покрывшийся плотной коркой. 2. Непропеченный, тяжёлый, плотный.
   Но мне кажется, что это не совсем точное и полное значение, если только более современное. Интересно эта тема изложена **у Даля:**

**КЛЕКНУТЬ**, южн. кур. вянуть и повиснуть; || сохнуть и черстветь; обветривать, дряблеть;. Цветочки клекнут. Клеклый, заклеклый, вялый. Клеклая редька. Клеклая земля, сухая и твердая, ровно камень. Клек м. что-либо сухое или твердое, крепкое, жесткое, заскорузлое, зачерствелое. Клёком стать, клёком взяться южн. затвердеть, зачерстветь. Сахар самый клёк, каменистый.
По поводу этимологии Даль сомневается: Нет ли связи между клекнуть, повисать вяло, клонить, клониться, и колено?

3. Если посмотреть **в Нацкорпусе** несколько примеров, то они тоже не укладываются в приведенные значения:  огурец из столовой, клеклый и кислый; клеклый деревенский хлеб; за бугром в степи клеклый чернозем что хрящ, тверда земля; клеклый, побуревший от старости лист бумаги; тесто получилось какое-то клеклое, и начинка выползла наружу; клеклый он был какой-то, мокроватенький (о человеке).
4. **В роли синонимов** предлагается такой ряд: вялый, заклеклый, клеклый, непропеченный, плотный, покрывшийся плотной коркой, ссохшийся; иногда – дряблый.  Слово «дряблый»  тоже характеризует нарушенную структуру, но это несколько другое качество.

ДРЯБЛЫЙ,  1. Лишённый свежести, упругости.  2. Чересчур мягкий, легко распадающийся на отдельные части, волокна (в результате ветхости, порчи, неправильного хранения и т.п.). Мясо оттаяло, стало дряблым. Переваренная рыба дрябла.

5. ***Клеклый*** в обобщенном смысле видится как  лишенный правильной структуры. Поэтому клеклым называют  как непропеченный, так и высохший хлеб,  неправильное тесто, вялый и мокрый внутри огурец, увядшую траву или цветы, то есть на первый взгляд  совершенно **разные качества.**

Из-за этой неопределенности  слово употребляется не часто, иногда надо объяснять, что вы имеете в виду, например: «Клёклый ― тяжелый, плотный. У меня вот такие получались и выглядели как не поднявшаяся масса, не рыхлая».  По словарю это действительно так, но вот наиболее частотным синонимом называют слово «вялый», а это отнюдь не плотный, да и клеклый огурец, к примеру, плотным не назовешь.

6. **Но каково же все-таки значение этого слова**? Для того чтобы использовать его в речи, мне необходимо чувствовать его **корневую основу.** Так как этимология слова неясная,  то  приходится ориентироваться на какие-то **ассоциации.**

Клеклая структура мне представляется как **"склеенная", сложившаяся, потерявшая свой пространственный объем** ― клёк, по Далю. Для **органических** структур это связано с потерей влаги, в других случаях – с потерей воздушного наполнения. Поэтому клеклым называют плотное тесто, не рыхлое, не воздушное. То же самое можно сказать о затвердевшей земле, лишенной влаги и воздуха.  Вялая органика лишена прежде всего воды, поэтому теряется ее упругость и пространственный объем.  Ну а клеклая рыба имеет **спрессованную плотную массу.**

7. Поэтому плотную однородную рыбу без волокон  можно  назвать клеклой. Другой вопрос, поймут ли вас окружающие, поэтому нелишне будет добавить пару синонимов: ***Рыба какая-то клеклая, плотная и без волокон.***

Comment: Спасибо большое! Ещё синоним "размазня".))